How to improve TTFB on NGINX?
I have a long TTFB (1.6 sec) and find the reason for this.
My stack is server (nginx + php-fpm) and load balancer on Hetzner and Cloudflare.
Are there too many redirects and therefore the waiting time is long?


My load balancer of Hetzner:

nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com api.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name  www.example.com api.example.com;
  root /var/www/app/public_html/web;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com-0001/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dh2048.pem;

  ssl_session_timeout 5m;

  ssl_session_cache shared:TLS:2m;
  ssl_buffer_size 4k;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;" always;


  include "conf.d/server_ssl.conf";
  include conf.d/drupal-prelive.conf;
  include conf.d/php_fpm_status-prelive.conf;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-app1.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx-app1-error.log;

  proxy_buffer_size   1024k;
  proxy_buffers    4 1024k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size   1024k;

  proxy_read_timeout 300;
  proxy_connect_timeout 300;
  proxy_send_timeout 300;

}

Page rule of Cloudflare:


nginx and any load balancers contribute really little to TTFB. Main contributor to TTFB is the PHP application you are running. To improve the application's performance, check your database server setup that it is optimized, and also check that caching on PHP side has been set up properly.


I have a long TTFB (1.6 sec) and find the reason for this

I presume you mean that you cannot find the reason for this.

Are there too many redirects

How do we know when you've replaced the host name with "www.example.com"? Why didn't you check before asking us?
If you turn off proxy buffering, you might get a faster response at the client......but so what? It's a recommendation from a bot which knows even less about your infrastructure than we do. It won't really help performance (it will reduce capacity) until you look at what your origin server is doing.

Yes, I cannot find the reason.
